# Set a variable on bash with the current date including tab

Tags: bash

I am trying to set a variable with the current date but having a tab between the date and the time. On the current variable I want also the time to be 1 hour back.

This works fine:

```
#date -d '1 hour ago' "+%Y-%m-%d"$'\t'"%H:"
2019-07-17      08:
```

But when I'm trying to set it to a variable the tab is replaced by space:

```
#var1=$(date -d '1 hour ago' "+%Y-%m-%d"$'\t'"%H:")
#echo $var1
2019-07-17 08:

#var1=`date -d '1 hour ago' "+%Y-%m-%d"$'\t'"%H:"`
#echo $var1
2019-07-17 08:
```

Any idea why this is happening and how i can include the tab in the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tab *is* in the variable. You're destroying it by *printing it wrong*.

```
echo "$var1"
# => 2019-07-17      08:
```

If you say just `echo $var1`, then `echo` gets two parameters separated by whitespace (your tab); `echo` prints each parameter separated by a space.

If you say `echo "$var1"`, then `echo` gets a single parameter, with tab included.

Comment: Thanks a lot Amadan! That makes sense..